# VBA - Lock a cell based on text in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using current code to send an email when a 'YES' is entered in column I:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim FormulaRange As Range
Dim NotSentMsg As String
Dim MyMsg As String
Dim SentMsg As String
Dim MyLimit As Double

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

MyLimit = 0

Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("S3:S100")

On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
        If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
            MyMsg = "Not numeric"
        Else
            If .Value > MyLimit Then
                MyMsg = SentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    Call Mail_with_outlook
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description
End Sub
```

I also have the following code to copy/paste certain values and locking the spreadsheet upon exit:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

'Step 1: Protect the sheet with a password
 Sheets("Sweden").Range("R3:R1000").Copy
 Sheets("Sweden").Range("Q3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 Sheets("Sweden").Range("A1").Select
 Sheets("Sweden").Protect Password:="password"
'Step 2: Save the workbook
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
 End Sub
```

Question and requirement: When 'YES' is entered in any cell in column I, the cell on the corresponding row in column H should be locked for editing and grey marked, i.e. no adjustments can be made to that value in column H. How can I incorporate this into the codes I have?

I tried using Data Validation for the cell in column H =IF(I5="YES",FALSE), which works but you are still able to delete the value in the cell.

And I also have another Data Validation in column H to restrict entering more than 2 decimals so I would like to use VBA as a solution.

Any advise on what VBA code to use and where to put it? See image of spreadsheet below.

[Current spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to9ui.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I can help you with:
Question and requirement: When 'YES' is entered in any cell in column I, the cell on the corresponding row in column H should be locked for editing and grey marked, i.e. no adjustments can be made to that value in column H. How can I incorporate this into the codes I have?

On the Sheet, where you want to do this, enter the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 9 And UCase(Target) = "YES" Then   'I is number 9
        Cells(Target.Row, 8).Interior.Color = 12566463
        Cells(Target.Row, 8).Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect "mypasswordissecurebecauseitisextremelylong"
    End If

End Sub
```

It would check for any yes (Yes, YES, yes, YeS) in column 9 and it would change the interior in column 8 to grey. Furthermore, it would lock the cell. 
In order to have it locked for editing, you should protect it by password.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However when I add this code in the current sheet (on top of the Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() already there, I get run time error 12 and debug points to row 'If Target.Column = 9 And UCase(Target) = "YES" Then   'I is number 9'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, first - never have seen run-time error 12. It is usually 13. But what I suppose, is that initially, all cells in your sheet may be locked, thus upon the second run your should get error `1004`. To go around this, select all cells from the beginning click properties and unmark the "locked" check. If you want to make sure how it works, open an empty Excel sheet and put the code there.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to write run-time error 13. I'm also using a 'Allow Users to Edit Ranges'. I.e. in column H there is a specific password in order to add any data. Guessing having both functions won't work? Anyway, when I unprotect sheet and assure all cells in column H and I are unlocked, then it works. However when I try to close the file run-time error 13 comes up again pointing at the same row in the code...?